# Use Fira Code font with ligatures in code listings

Tags: xetex, ligatures

I would like to use the [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) OTF font for code listings and verbatim blocks, which has beautiful ligatures. The font loads correctly using the following line:

```
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular}
```

But I cannot get the ligatures to work, no matter how many combinations of `[Ligatures={X}]` or `[RawFeatures={X}]` I try.

Is there any way to make them work with `xelatex`?

Comment: What is a ligature in a code listing?

Comment: @AFeldman You should have a look at the Fira Code font that he links to.  It contains the examples of the ligature that this font introduces.

Comment: Welcome! Can you post a complete minimal example people can compile? Does LuaLaTeX work any better?

Comment: @JP-Ellis thanks, kind of freaky looking, but that's from a non-programmer's perspective.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to make sure that Fira Code is installed on your computer (which I'm sure you already do).

The font features that Fira Code uses aren't actually listed as ligatures within the OTF, but seems to be fall under *Contextuals*.  In order to use these font features, it is just a matter of enabling the appropriate contextuals:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[
  Contextuals={Alternate}
]{Fira Code}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
           .= .- := =:=
        == != === !== =/=

    <<- <-- <- <-> -> --> ->>
<=< <<= <==    <=> => ==> =>> >=>
    >>= >>- >-     -< -<< =<<
        <~~ <~ ~~~ ~> ~~>

     <<< << <= <>  >= >> >>>
            <| <|> |>

            <$ <$> $>
            <+ <+> +>
            <* <*> *>

       \\ \\\ {- -} // ///
          /* /** **/ */ 
      </ <!-- www  --> />
      0xF  9:45  m-x *ptr

       ;; ;;; :: ::: !! !!!
       ?? ??? %% %%% && &&& 
       || ||| .. ... ..< []
       -- --- ++ +++ ** ***

          ~= ~- -~ =~ ~@
        ^= ?= /= /== |= ||=
           ## ### ####
         #{ #[ #( #? #_ #_(


a*b a*A B*b A*B *a *A a* A*
a-b a-A B-b A-B -a -A a- A-
a+b a+A B+b A+B +a +A a+ A+
a:b a:A B:b A:B :a :A a: A:
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that I'm still trying to figure out why certain substitutions work (such as `.=`) but some others don't (such as `.-`).  I suspect it may be do `-` being converted from the ASCII dash to some other dash.

Just for reference, the ligatures from Fira Code are:

[image: reference]

The “missing” ligatures can be obtained by removing the characters `verbatim` wants to treat in a special way because traditional TeX fonts have ligatures; by default, `fontspec` doesn't apply `Ligatures=TeX` to the monospaced font, so there's no risk in redefining `\verbatim@noligs@list` to empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont[
  Contextuals={Alternate}
]{Fira Code}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
           .= .- := =:=
        == != === !== =/=

    <<- <-- <- <-> -> --> ->>
<=< <<= <==    <=> => ==> =>> >=>
    >>= >>- >-     -< -<< =<<
        <~~ <~ ~~~ ~> ~~>

     <<< << <= <>  >= >> >>>
            <| <|> |>

            <$ <$> $>
            <+ <+> +>
            <* <*> *>

       \\ \\\ {- -} // ///
          /* /** **/ */ 
      </ <!-- www  --> />
      0xF  9:45  m-x *ptr

       ;; ;;; :: ::: !! !!!
       ?? ??? %% %%% && &&& 
       || ||| .. ... ..< []
       -- --- ++ +++ ** ***

          ~= ~- -~ =~ ~@
        ^= ?= /= /== |= ||=
           ## ### ####
         #{ #[ #( #? #_ #_(


a*b a*A B*b A*B *a *A a* A*
a-b a-A B-b A-B -a -A a- A-
a+b a+A B+b A+B +a +A a+ A+
a:b a:A B:b A:B :a :A a: A:
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great. Thanks! Out of curiosity, what tool did you use to analyze the OTF file?

Comment: I used fontforge to analyse the OTF file, that's how I figured that Fira Code implements these replacement.

Comment: The ligatures with the dashes don't work as the dash is in `\verbatim@nolig@list`, a command that `\verb` uses to suppress actively ligatures with these chars.

Comment: Very nice! +50 in a few days.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for the edit!  Confirms my hunch and fixes most of the ligatures :)  Interesting that there's still a couple of ligatures which don't appear (the ones I could notice: `~~~`, `{- -}` `=~`).

Comment: @JP-Ellis It's especially interesting, that they do not appear *anymore*.  In your original answer they were there.  Something must have changed in the meantime.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but I have an additional question: how to get this to work with `Verbatim` from the `fancyvrb` package? Changing `\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}` to `\def\Verbatim@nolig@list{}` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Oh wait, that's quite odd. Now, it does work, though I don't think I changed anything... But, it seems as if just using `\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}` in the first place, does the trick already.

Comment: **Note**: If you use only this answer, it is insufficient to enable all ligatures. Refer to [the comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294362/use-fira-code-font-with-ligatures-in-code-listings#comment888783_294369) or [fontspec - How can I enable ligatures in verbatim environments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360533/how-can-i-enable-ligatures-in-verbatim-environments/360548#360548).

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to use Fira Code in ConTeXt.  However, not all ligatures seem to work there.  Unfortunately I have no idea why.

```
\definefontfeature
  [firacode-ligs]
  [mode=node,
   calt=yes]

\starttypescriptcollection[firacode]

  \starttypescript [mono] [firacode]
    \definefontsynonym [FiraCodeBold]    [file:FiraCode-Bold.otf]    [features=firacode-ligs] 
    \definefontsynonym [FiraCodeLight]   [file:FiraCode-Light.otf]   [features=firacode-ligs] 
    \definefontsynonym [FiraCodeMedium]  [file:FiraCode-Medium.otf]  [features=firacode-ligs] 
    \definefontsynonym [FiraCodeRegular] [file:FiraCode-Regular.otf] [features=firacode-ligs] 
    \definefontsynonym [FiraCodeRetina]  [file:FiraCode-Retina.otf]  [features=firacode-ligs] 
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [mono] [firacode] [name]
    \setups[font:fallback:mono]
    \definefontsynonym [Mono]     [FiraCodeRegular]
    \definefontsynonym [MonoBold] [FiraCodeBold]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [firacode]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [rm] [serif] [modern]   [default] [features=default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [ss] [sans]  [modern]   [default] [features=default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [tt] [mono]  [firacode] [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [mm] [math]  [modern]   [default] [features=default]
  \stoptypescript

\stoptypescriptcollection

\setupbodyfont[firacode]

\starttext

\starttyping
           .= .- := =:=
        == != === !== =/=

    <<- <-- <- <-> -> --> ->>
<=< <<= <==    <=> => ==> =>> >=>
    >>= >>- >-     -< -<< =<<
        <~~ <~ ~~~ ~> ~~>

     <<< << <= <>  >= >> >>>
            <| <|> |>

            <$ <$> $>
            <+ <+> +>
            <* <*> *>

       \\ \\\ {- -} // ///
          /* /** **/ */ 
      </ <!-- www  --> />
      0xF  9:45  m-x *ptr

       ;; ;;; :: ::: !! !!!
       ?? ??? %% %%% && &&& 
       || ||| .. ... ..< []
       -- --- ++ +++ ** ***

          ~= ~- -~ =~ ~@
        ^= ?= /= /== |= ||=
           ## ### ####
         #{ #[ #( #? #_ #_(


a*b a*A B*b A*B *a *A a* A*
a-b a-A B-b A-B -a -A a- A-
a+b a+A B+b A+B +a +A a+ A+
a:b a:A B:b A:B :a :A a: A:
\stoptyping

\stoptext
```

[image]