# How can I enable ligatures in verbatim environments?

Tags: fontspec, verbatim, code, ligatures

I have [Fira Code with ligatures enabled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294362/use-fira-code-font-with-ligatures-in-code-listings) as my default mono font using `fontspec`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect on `verbatim` or `lstlisting` environments.

Why are those contexts different, and how can I fix it to get these ligatures everywhere?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Contextuals={Alternate}]{FiraCode}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\section{tt}

{\tt ->}

\section{verb}

\verb|->|

\section{verbatim}

\begin{verbatim}
->
\end{verbatim}

\section{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
->
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Rendered with lualatex:

[image]

Comment: The `verbatim`- and `lstlisting`-environments are made to represent code and not the effect the code would have. Therefore it is not desirable to have ligatures inside of them.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Fira Code` instead of `FiraCode` ? Are you sure you  have the right spelling in your file?

Comment: @Skillmon I don't know what you mean by "the effect code would have", but the [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) ligatures are specifically designed to display code.

Comment: @ilFuria It works with or without the space, doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: @ChrisMartin: I mean it is designed to print out exactly what you gave it. Not processing your code in any other way. For me a ligature of `->` doesn't make sense, because I won't ever use that kind of character in any programming language I know. But for example in C I use the combination `->` for lists.

Comment: @ChrisMartin what I'm trying to say is, that it is the design and sense of `lstlisting` or `verbatim` to not evaluate any contents you give them (except for `lstlisting` performing stuff like syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @Skillmon So perhaps I'm looking for a different environment for my code blocks then?

Comment: you can use the rightarrow character directly but as @Skillmon says verbatim environments go to some lengths to break ligartures, if you were showing (say) c code you would want `->`  (legal c syntax) not `→` (a syntax error)

Comment: @ChrisMartin May I ask, why you need those ligatures?

Comment: @Skillmon There are a lot of operators in Haskell that look very nice with these ligatures, and in the context of the book I'm working on, its intended audience having intermediate-level Haskell knowledge, it will be clear what source characters they represent.

Comment: See the "literate programming" section of the `listings` manual which describes how to make suitable substitutions.

Comment: Surely it would be clearer to actually show the code people should type and not something they have to interpret into code they should type? Aesthetics are important, but they are surely secondary to the meaning you are conveying.  `\tt` has been obsolete for 20+ years in LaTeX and ought not be used in documents using 2e. Unless you are still running 2.09, you shouldn't use it. (And if you are running 2.09, I think the rest of the code is probably wrong, but that's before my time.)

Comment: @cfr The meaning of the arrows is exceedingly obvious in context, and the rest of the ligatures are minor positioning adjustments that shift groups of characters that form infix operators closer together.

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX actively suppress the ligatures of `-` and `>` in verbatim context through the `\verbatim@nolig@list`. You can change/empty this list but be aware that it can affect other combinations too. listings works differently. Here you can use the literate option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.otf}[Contextuals={Alternate}]
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        literate={->}{\texttt{->}}{1}}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily ->  -- >>}


\verb|-> -- >>|

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}%
\makeatother
\verb|-> -- >>|

\begin{lstlisting}
-> -- >>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]