# How to enable contextual substitutions in lstlisting?

Tags: fonts, listings, opentype

Fira Code (available via its [GitHub Release page](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases)) not only provides fancy programming ligatures (see [Use Fira Code font with ligatures in code listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294362)), but also contains contextual substitutions. For example, the colon character `:` is usually vertically aligned with respect to lowercase letters, so it will appear misaligned when it is placed between uppercase letters and/or lining numerals. But Fira Code, when *Contextual Alternates* is enabled, can substitute the lowercase-friendly `:` with an uppercase-friendly one.

The *Contextual Alternates* feature does not work in a `lstlisting` environment. For the ligatures, there is [`lstfiracode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lstfiracode) (shameless plug), but how can one get the rest of contextual substitutions as mentioned above?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.otf}[
  Contextuals=Alternate
]
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
With \verb|verbatim|:
\begin{verbatim}
0xff 0xFF % x is contextually substituted
a-c  A-C  % - is contextually substituted
e+g  1+2  % + is contextually substituted
i*j  3*4  % * is contextually substituted
m:n  5:6  % : is contextually substituted
\end{verbatim}
With \verb|lstlisting|:
\begin{lstlisting}
0xff 0xFF
a-c  A-C
e+g  1+2
i*j  3*4
m:n  5:6
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Contextual Alternates]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inspect the output with \showoutput you can see that listings inserts stuff between the glyphs: space (glue) and \hbox. Both interfere with the contextual substituation.

Possible ways to avoid it are:

- literate as in your sty
- `columns=fullflexible` to avoid that glue is inserted
- declaring some input as a letter to avoid that listings separate it.

Every one can have side effects on the processing of listings of keywords and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.otf}[
  Contextuals=Alternate
]
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\showoutput 
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
0xff 0xFF
a-c  A-C
i*j  3*4
m:n  5:6  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\lstset{
  literate={0xff}{{0xff}}4,
  }
\begin{lstlisting}
0xff 0xFF
a-c  A-C
i*j  3*4
m:n  5:6
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\lstset{
  columns=flexible,
  alsoletter={0,*,-}
  }
\begin{lstlisting}
0xff 0xFF
a-c  A-C
i*j  3*4
m:n  5:6
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing such comprehensive solutions! I will need to decide which one(s) to implement. Side note: I noticed in your picture the default zeros are dotted zeros, which was changed since [Release 1.205](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases/tag/1.205) more than a year ago. The default zero now is slashed zero.