# Spurious newline inserted by lstlisting when using the font BQN386

Tags: fonts, listings

I have a listing rendering problem with source code from the BQN programming language. I use `lualatex` (`LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)`). I tested various fonts and the result is the same. The fonts come from https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/fonts.html and in particular BQN386 is at https://github.com/dzaima/BQN386.

A spurious newline is inserted before `8` by `lstlisting` and the space before `↕` has disappeared. The same line using the `verbatim` environment or with `verb` is ok. Note that I cannot use the command `lstinline` because of an error. It looks like those special characters are messing with how `listings` interprets them.

Here is the relevant part of the generated pdf:

[image]

I have checked [Latex: Listings with monospace fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2913141/452614), [How to enable contextual substitutions in lstlisting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485981/4735) and [Use JetBrains Mono ligatures with fontspec and lstlisting environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547547/4735).

Any idea to render the source code properly ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{BQN386}

\usepackage{listings}
% \lstset{inputencoding=utf8,extendedchars=true}
\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    % columns = flexible,
    % keepspaces = true,
    % alsoletter={↕},
}

% \lstdefinelanguage{BQN}{ %
%   alsoletter=⌽⊸⌈↕, %
% }
% \lstset{language=BQN}

% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

OK: {\tt ⌽⊸⌈ ↕8}. OK: \verb+⌽⊸⌈ ↕8+.
% File ended while scanning use of \lst@temp.
% Or \lstinline!⌽⊸⌈ ↕8!.

\par OK:
\begin{verbatim}
⌽⊸⌈ ↕8
\end{verbatim}

\par Not OK:
\begin{lstlisting}
⌽⊸⌈ ↕8
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup the characters explicitly for `listings`. For APL you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25796/. The character ⊸ (`0x22b8`) is missing there, I have added that one below. Now also `\lstinline` works properly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{BQN386}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    % columns = flexible,
    % keepspaces = true,
    % alsoletter={↕},
}

% set lstlisting to accept UTF8 APL text
% from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25796/
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  ^^^^20ac^^^^0153^^^^0152%
  ^^^^20a7^^^^2190^^^^2191^^^^2192^^^^2193^^^^2206^^^^2207^^^^220a%
  ^^^^2218^^^^2228^^^^2229^^^^222a^^^^2235^^^^223c^^^^2260^^^^2261%
  ^^^^2262^^^^2264^^^^2265^^^^2282^^^^2283^^^^2296^^^^22a2^^^^22a3%
  ^^^^22a4^^^^22a5^^^^22b8^^^^22c4^^^^2308^^^^230a^^^^2336^^^^2337^^^^2339%
  ^^^^233b^^^^233d^^^^233f^^^^2340^^^^2342^^^^2347^^^^2348^^^^2349%
  ^^^^234b^^^^234e^^^^2350^^^^2352^^^^2355^^^^2357^^^^2359^^^^235d%
  ^^^^235e^^^^235f^^^^2361^^^^2362^^^^2363^^^^2364^^^^2365^^^^2368%
  ^^^^236a^^^^236b^^^^236c^^^^2371^^^^2372^^^^2373^^^^2374^^^^2375%
  ^^^^2377^^^^2378^^^^237a^^^^2395^^^^25af^^^^25ca^^^^25cb%
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother


% \lstdefinelanguage{BQN}{ %
%   alsoletter=⌽⊸⌈↕, %
% }
% \lstset{language=BQN}

% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

OK: {\tt ⌽⊸⌈ ↕8}. OK: \verb+⌽⊸⌈ ↕8+.

Or \lstinline!⌽⊸⌈ ↕8!.

\par OK:
\begin{verbatim}
⌽⊸⌈ ↕8
\end{verbatim}

\par Not OK:
\begin{lstlisting}
⌽⊸⌈ ↕8
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why it is `^^` or `^^^^` ? What does that mean ?

Comment: @LudovicKuty see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62725/the-notation-in-various-engines